# Как переслать документ, отправленный пользователем боту в телеграмм, в другой чат?(Telebot)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня возникла проблема. Пишу бота на Python с помощью Telebot.Нужно чтобы пользователь отправлял excel файл боту, а бот уже в свою очередь пересылал этот файл в другой чат. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("") #токен бота

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["document"])
def send(message):
    idd = 00000 #чат id, куда переслать
    bot.forward_message(idd, message.chat.id, message.id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

нужно принять файл(в функции send), ввести в переменную idd, id того чата, в который нужно переслать.